# Apple's Push Notification Service Implementation Options

Tags: php, ios, http, apple-push-notifications

Basically what I want to do is have a server which does the following:

- Query an RSS feed for updates every # minutes
- If there are updates, send a push notification to my iOS app

All of the tutorials I have read for implementing Apple's Push Notification service use a PHP script server-side. How can I adapt this to have a continuously running process?

**Note:** I have done very little server work, so it would be appreciated if explanations are given for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a continuously running process? You could use a [Crontab](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) for querying the RSS feed and invoke the "are there any updates -> send push notification"-script on completion.

Are you relying on PHP or which technology do you intend to use for your server side?

// edit: You don't have to stick to PHP, e.g. I'm running a Tomcat server (Java). For sending APNS, I'm making use of the third party library [javapns](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/).

Comment: If it is possible to use another language to communicate with APNS, then I am open to suggestions. I apologize for my ignorance, but what is a Crontab?

Comment: The server can run any language you want it to.  Interoperability is not dependent on the *language*.  It's dependent on what the developer *does* with their language of choice.

Comment: Crontab is the main way you schedule things to run on Linux- and other Unix-like servers.  Google it.  :-)  As alluded to above, you could have a PHP script that does the RSS checking, and schedule it on your server's crontab to run every X minutes.  No need for a continuously-running script in PHP, or any other language for that matter.